# Is Nullable<T>.Equals Method Implementation Wrong?

Tags: c#, oop

I am talking about C# language here.

Definition of Object.Equals(Object) method in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) is:

> Determines whether the specified
>   Object is equal to the current Object.

If two objects are equal it returns true, however if they are null it returns false:

> x.Equals(a null reference (Nothing in
>   Visual Basic)) returns false.

Why? Because null is not an object.

A NullReferenceException is thrown if the object paremeter is null.

and also we have this:

> x.Equals(y) returns the same value as
>   y.Equals(x).

No problem at all till here. It is very similar to Java. But C# also provides a `System.Nullable` struct for non-nullable types. As far as I know, a struct is an object. It inherits Object.Equals method.

If I have a struct like this:

```
struct Car
    {
        public string Make;
        public string Model;
        public uint Year;

        public Car(string make, string model, uint year)
        {
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
            Year = year;
        }
    }
```

And create four instances:

```
Car car1 = new Car("make", "model", 2009);
Car car2 = new Car("make", "model", 2009);
Car car3 = new Car("make", "model", 2008);

car1.Equals(car2); // will return true
car1.Equals(car3); // will return false;
```

And as far as I know we can't set a struct to a null value. But System.Nullable is a struct and we can do compile this without any errors:

```
int? i = null;
```

(I hope that someone can explain this also. Is it a struct or something else?)

My real question is:

```
i.Equals(null); // returns true!
```

(Normally  x.Equals(y) = y.Equals(x) Of course null.Equals(i) is not valid here... )

Obviously Object.Equals method is overridden here. Maybe it is documented and this is specified. But is this approach correct/nice ? If so what is the difference between == and Equals method for Nullable values?

Comment: To answer your last question. If `Car? ncar1 = ...;` is a `Nullable<>`, then `ncar1 == null` and `ncar1.Equals(null)` is typically the same. Both will just check if `ncar1.HasValue` is `false`. But if we also have `Car? ncar2 = ...;`, then `ncar1 == ncar2` and `ncar1.Equals(ncar2)` _might_ be different, dependant on whether the `Car` struct type overloads `operator ==` in a way that is equivalent to the appropriate overload of `.Equals` (which may be `.Equals(object)` overridden by `Car` or just  overridden by `System.ValueType`, or may be `.Equals(Car)` if that overload is declared).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your confusion is rooted in the following line

```
i? = null;
```

This does not actually create a null value variable.  It's essentially syntatic sugar for the following

```
Nullable<int> i = new Nullable<int>();
```

The resulting property HasValue on i will have the value false.  It is not null but instead a value type with empty values.  Or just an empty nullable.  IMHO, the best way to think of this is that null is convertible to an empty `Nullable<T>` for any given T.

Knowing that it makes the line i.Equals(null) a bit easier to understand.  It's syntatic sugar for the following

```
Nullable<int> i = new Nullable<int>();
i.Equals(null);
```

The type `Nullable<T>` only overrides Equals(object).  The implementation of this method though considers a null value to be Equal to an empty nullable value.  So it's behaving correctly.

Comment: But, whatever it does in the background we call i.Equals(null) and it returns true when i is null. It should return false for any other object.

Comment: @jcasso, Nullable's in general are ... weird and often behave in unexpected ways.  Part of the confusion is that i can't ever be null because it is in fact a value type.  It's better to think of it as an empty nullable.

Comment: At least you accepted that it is weird :) I thought that I was the only one.

Comment: Note that the _static_ method `Object.Equals(null, null)` will return true, so it's well-established that `null` is equal to `null`. The only reason why you get a `NullReferenceException` when you call `null.Equals(y)` is because semantics of instance method calls on reference types demand that; it has nothing to do with semantics of `Equals` itself. Since `Nullable<T>` is not a reference type, this doesn't apply.

Comment: Like I pointed out in the other post, i.Equals(null) is not calling Object.Equals. It is a virtual call constrained to the Nullable<int> type.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your side question, Nullable is a struct with a T: Struct constraint. So, even though int? i = null; is null, i is an instance of the Nullable struct.

Comment: A struct may take null value? Can you define Car car4 = null; ?

Comment: Struct cannot have a `null` value as far as CLR is concerned. In C#, when you write `int? x = null`, you are actually writing `int? x = new int?()`. There's no real `null` involved there at all.

Comment: no. but when you do int? i = <<some legal value>>, the CLR puts that legal value into the value property of i. Also, just FYI, Nullable overrides the Equals method

Comment: Also, looking at the IL underneath a call to int? i = null; The CLR loads the address that it has assigned to the variable, then initializes an empty Nullable<int> object (with null fields) into that address.

Comment: @pavel: much more concise way to say what i was trying to say in my second comment :)